# How to customize Open Graph story?

Tags: ios, facebook-opengraph

I'm new to using Open Graph, and don't see where in the Facebook tutorials or doc's it says how to do this. This is done on iOS 8 in Xcode 6.

I want my sentence to say

```
I just got a score of *350*! Can you beat it?
```

But don't know how to take my `self.score` to add it to the open graph story!

I have no code to display because the tutorial from Facebook is out of date. IF anyone can please provide me better code that does not error with custom Open Graph (or a better solution) for posting the line above, I'll be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Because the Facebook code is wrong I'll explain how I found a way to do it, then post the full code.

I forgot the open graph idea and decided to just post a simple conditional string triggered by a button. From there I used Facebook's code from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share#linkfeed), only using the fallback as the "Share Dialog" above it does not fully work.

From there I just used `[NSString stringWithFormat:%@%@%@,string1,self.score,string2];`

Here is sample code (modified to be generic for others):

```
-(IBAction)facebookShare:(id)sender {

//Set Variables
int scoreText
int highScoreText

//Format the description
NSString *description;
NSString *t1 = @"I just got a score of ";
NSString *t1Alt = @"I just got a new high score of ";
NSString *t2 = @"! Can you beat it?";
if (self.newHigh == NO){
    description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",t1,scoreText,t2];
} else if (self.newHigh == YES){
    description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@",t1Alt,highScoreText,t2];
}

// Put together the dialog parameters
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Edit Me", @"name",
                               @"Edit Me", @"caption",
                               description, @"description",
                               @"http://Edit.Me.Too/", @"link",
                               @"http://And.Me.Too/", @"picture",
                               nil];

/* * * * * * * * * * * DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * * * * * * * * * * *
 *                                                                       *
 *                                                                       *
 *               From here on, this shows share screen                   *                         
 * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * */
[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                       parameters:params
                                          handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                              if (error) {
                                                  // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                                  // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                                  NSLog(@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description);
                                              } else {
                                                  if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                                                      // User cancelled.
                                                      NSLog(@"User cancelled.");
                                                  } else {
                                                      // Handle the publish feed callback
                                                      NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];

                                                      if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]) {
                                                          // User cancelled.
                                                          NSLog(@"User cancelled.");

                                                      } else {
                                                          // User clicked the Share button
                                                          NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Posted story, id: %@", [urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]];
                                                          NSLog(@"result %@", result);
                                                      }
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          }];
```

}